# Can we add image path (of local database) to the android APP widget (Home Screen Widget)?

Tags: flutter, kotlin, android-appwidget

Context: I am creating a flutter app wherein the screenshot of a particular app-page needs to be shown in app widget.
On Android side, we are using Kotlin (which I have no idea of, I don't even know if this thing is possible).

Path provided by flutter will be like:
/data/user/0/com.example.myboardapp/app_flutter/20220613_151934.jpg